# Isotope: Irregular heights on initial Masonry load

Tags: jquery-isotope

Having some trouble with an Isotope / Masonry layout. On imagesLoaded, the script is adding large vertical gaps to a few items.

After filtering the page and then going back to the initial view (that is, the home page), all of the items are laid out correctly with the correct vertical spacing. You can see it in action here: http://bne-flexo.hostnetworks.com.au/~reclaim/

The vertical gaps seem to correspond to the natural height of the images being loaded. I've added a script to constrain the width and height of the image in the HTML code - ie. width and height attributes to the  tag. That doesn't appear to be helping Isotope perform its calculations.

It would be lovely if my client could be taught to only upload correctly re-sized images, but that ain't gonna happen.

So I'm stuck wondering what's going to be the best way to help Isotope calculate the vertical spacing correctly. 
Is there a way to pass 'correct' height values to Isotope?
Can I force Isotope to refresh its layout as soon as it's finished its initial layout?
Any other thoughts..?

Cheers,
Dan